# Implement the scroll func in React without using DOM selector

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I'm new to React. Is there any way to implement scrolling my chat window to the bottom when a new message has been sent without using selectors?

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class ChatWindow extends Component {

  componentDidUpdate() {
    document.querySelector('.chat-window').scroll(0, 999);
  }

  render() {
    const mappedMessages = this.props.messages.map((item) => {
      return <p key={item._id} className="message light-grey">
        <Link className="link" to=''>{item.author}:</Link> 
        {item.msg}
      </p>
    });

    return <div className="chat-window">
      {mappedMessages}
    </div>
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the [Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) feature.

So you can create a `ref` using `React.createRef()`. Then you just need to assign it as a `ref` attribute to the needed element. After that you can reach a node reference via `current` property of your created ref.

If you use `React` older than 16.3 - please consider to examine [callback refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class ChatWindow extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.chatRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.chatRef.current.scroll(0, 900)
  }

  render() {
    const mappedMessages = this.props.messages.map((item) => {
      return <p key={item._id} className="message light-grey">
        <Link className="link" to=''>{item.author}:</Link>
        {item.msg}
      </p>
    });

    return <div className="chat-window" ref={this.chatRef}>
      {mappedMessages}
    </div>
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I've completely forgotten about Refs.